# ExitWindowsEx with EWX_RESTARTAPPS does not reboot anymore

Tags: windows-10

I'm calling the [`ExitWindowsEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376868%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) function in my application with the `EWX_RESTARTAPPS` flag to reboot the computer and restart most applications. This has worked fine in Windows 7, but in Windows 10 all it does is log off the user. I can log back in immediately and Windows was not restarted.

Does that application restarting thing work at all, is it any good, or should I not even try and just use the `EWX_REBOOT` flag if that works?

Update: Rebooting doesn't work either, it returns a negative result. My process is running as Administrator, isn't that enough to reboot Windows 10? It says "the client is missing a required right" or so, error code 1314.

Comment: 1314 = ERROR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD: https://www.google.com/search?q=exitwindowsex+error_privilege_not_held  you have to call  the AdjustTokenPrivileges function to enable the SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME privilege.

Comment: Okay, but the original flag doesn't give that error, it just doesn't reboot as documented. I think the documentation is wrong, it has changed in Windows 8 or 10, now the EWX_RESTARTAPPS is useless.